# Как сделать перенос записей в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать вот такой перенос записей в table?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почитайте про drag & drop

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй с помощью Dragula JS:

```js
/* Custom Dragula JS */
dragula([
  document.getElementById("to-do"),
  document.getElementById("doing")
]);
removeOnSpill: false
  .on("drag", function(el) {
    el.className.replace("ex-moved", "");
  })
  .on("drop", function(el) {
    el.className += "ex-moved";
  })
  .on("over", function(el, container) {
    container.className += "ex-over";
  })
  .on("out", function(el, container) {
    container.className.replace("ex-over", "");
  });

function addTask() {
  var inputTask = document.getElementById("taskText").value;
  document.getElementById("to-do").innerHTML +=
    "<li class='task'><p>" + inputTask + "</p></li>";
  document.getElementById("taskText").value = "";
}


Стили:
```

```css
.main-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.columns {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 1.6rem auto;
}

.column {
  width: 8.4rem;
  margin: 0 0.6rem;
  background: #a8a8a8;
  border: #000013 0.2rem solid;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
}

.column-header {
  padding: 0.1rem;
  border-bottom: #000013 0.2rem solid;
}

.column-header h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.to-do-column .column-header {
  background: #ff872f;
}

.doing-column .column-header {
  background: #13a4d9;
}

.done-column .column-header {
  background: #15d072;
}

.lang-list {
  min-height: 3rem;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.lang {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin: 0.4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border: #000013 0.15rem solid;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  cursor: move;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.gu-mirror {
  position: fixed !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.gu-hide {
  display: none !important;
}

.gu-unselectable {
  -webkit-user-select: none !important;
  -moz-user-select: none !important;
  -ms-user-select: none !important;
  user-select: none !important;
}

.gu-transit {
  opacity: 0.2;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}

Подключаем скрипт в html.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragula/3.7.2/dragula.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <ul class="columns">

    <li class="column to-do-column">
      <div class="column-header">
        <h4>Список языков</h4>
      </div>
      <ul class="lang-list" id="to-do">
        <li class="lang">
          <p>Язык 1</p>
        </li>
        <li class="lang">
          <p>Язык 2</p>
        </li>
        <li class="lang">
          <p>Язык 3</p>
        </li>
        <li class="lang">
          <p>Язык 4</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="column doing-column">
      <div class="column-header">
        <h4>Выбранные языки</h4>
      </div>
      <ul class="lang-list" id="doing">
        <li class="lang">
          <p>Язык 5</p>
        </li>
        <li class="lang">
          <p>Язык 6</p>
        </li>
        <li class="lang">
          <p>Язык 7</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]